# how to get values by class instead of id in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem in getting values by class.I want to put class instead of id as i am not getting required results using id.how can i get values using (.) instead of (#) in below code.i tried but not getting results.if anyone have solution then please help and give me solution.i shall be very thankful.

here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                                                                                                                                                   
$(function () {                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
$("#handshake").click(function (e) {                                                                                                                                                                       
e.preventDefault();                                                                                                                                                                                    
$("#handshake").attr('disabled', 'disabled');                                                                                                                                                          
submitRequest("HandshakeForm");                                                                                                                                                                        
if ($("#HS_IsRedirectionRequest").val() == "1") {                                                                                                                                                      
        document.getElementById("HandshakeForm").submit();                                                                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    else {                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        var myData = {                                                                                                                                                                                     
            HS_MerchantId : $("#HS_MerchantId").val(),                                                                                                                                                     
            HS_StoreId : $("#HS_StoreId").val(),                                                                                                                                                     
            HS_MerchantHash : $("#HS_MerchantHash").val(),                                                                                                                                                 
            HS_MerchantUsername : $("#HS_MerchantUsername").val(),                                                                                                                                         
            HS_MerchantPassword : $("#HS_MerchantPassword").val(),                                                                                                                                         
            HS_IsRedirectionRequest : $("#HS_IsRedirectionRequest").val(),                                                                                                                                 
            HS_ReturnURL : $("#HS_ReturnURL").val(),                                                                                                                                                       
            HS_RequestHash : $("#HS_RequestHash").val(),                                                                                                                                                   
            HS_ChannelId: $("#HS_ChannelId").val(),                                                                                                                                                        
            HS_TransactionReferenceNumber: $("#HS_TransactionReferenceNumber").val(),                                                                                                                      
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        $.ajax({                                                                                                                                                                                           
            type: 'POST',                                                                                                                                                                                  
            url: 'https://sandbox.bankalfalah.com/HS/HS/HS',                                                                                                                                            
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",                                                                                                                                                
            data: myData,                                                                                                                                                                  
            dataType: "json",                                                                                                                                                                              
            beforeSend: function () {                                                                                                                                                                      
            },                                                                                                                                                                                             
            success: function (r) {                                                                                                                                                                        
                if (r != '') {                                                                                                                                                                             
                    if (r.success == "true") {                                                                                                                                                             
                        $("#AuthToken").val(r.AuthToken);                                                                                                                                                  
                        $("#ReturnURL").val(r.ReturnURL);                                                                                                                                                  
                        alert('Success: Handshake Successful');                                                                                                                                
                    }                                                                                                                                                                                      
                    else                                                                                                                                                                                      
                    {                                                                                                                                                                                      
                        alert('Error: Handshake Unsuccessful');                                                                                                                                                                                       
                    }                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                }                                                                                                                                                                                          
                else                                                                                                                                                                                          
                {                                                                                                                                                                                          
                    alert('Error: Handshake Unsuccessful');                                                                                                                                                                                            
                }                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            },                                                                                                                                                                                             
            error: function (error) {                                                                                                                                                                      
                alert('Error: An error occurred');                                                                                                                                               
            },                                                                                                                                                                                             
            complete: function(data) {                                                                                                                                                                     
                $("#handshake").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');                                                                                                                                        
            }                                                                                                                                                                                              
        });                                                                                                                                                                                                
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
});                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
$("#run").click(function (e) {                                                                                                                                                                             
    e.preventDefault();                                                                                                                                                                                    
    submitRequest("PageRedirectionForm");                                                                                                                                                                  
    document.getElementById("PageRedirectionForm").submit();                                                                                                                                               
     });                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 });                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 function submitRequest(formName) {                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
var mapString = '', hashName = 'RequestHash';                                                                                                                                                              
if (formName == "HandshakeForm") {                                                                                                                                                                         
    hashName = 'HS_' + hashName;                                                                                                                                                                           
}                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
$("#" + formName+" :input").each(function () {                                                                                                                                                             
    if ($(this).attr('id') != '') {                                                                                                                                                                        
        mapString += $(this).attr('id') + '=' + $(this).val() + '&';                                                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                      
});                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
$("#" + hashName).val(CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(mapString.substr(0, 
 mapString.length - 1)), CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse($("#Key1").val()),                                                  
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        keySize: 128 / 8,                                                                                                                                                                                  
        iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse($("#Key2").val()),                                                                                                                                                     
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,                                                                                                                                                                           
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7                                                                                                                                                                        
    }));                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 }                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 </script>
```

Comment: The fact you are not getting them by both class and id points to to trying by class not being the solution. Have you tried trying to get the value via `$('input[id="HS_MerchantId"]').val()` ? Are the fields sat in an iFrame by any chance as well?

Comment: Can you provide *minimal* code that *demonstrates* the problem (see [mcve]).  As it is, it's hard to see which lines you're talking about.  Include the relevant HTML.

Comment: "*want to put class instead of id as i am not getting required results using id*"  could be because you have the ID repeated multiple times - or just the ID doesn't match.  Either way, seeing the HTML is the only way to diagnose your XY problem.

Comment: sir i am getting results but not my required results.there are 3 input radio button which have same name but different ids due to this js code  reads only one id and i can't repeat ids in all 3 radio inputs as you know ids are unique so thats why i want to use classes because classes can be used more than one..have you got my point?

Comment: Can't see any radio buttons in your question / code / snippet.  There's a lot of what appears to be irrelevant (to the question) crypto code and a post with a long (irrelevant?) callback.  Please include your HTML in the question along with only *relevant* code.

Comment: sir i cant post html code here bcoz its too long.i told you scenario.if you have solution then let me know please

Answer (score 0):

The `$()` function from jquery can select by any css path so it is simply possible to do `$('.HS_MerchantId')`. However it is important to remember that an `id` can only appear once in the document, where a `class` can be reused as much as needed. jQuery knows this and where `$('#HS_MerchantId').val()` works because it only returns a single object, namely the first element with the `HS_Merchant_Id`, `$('.HS_MerchantId').val()` will not, because jQuery selecting classes will return a list wich contains ALL elements that match, even if there is only one.

Therefore you would need to loop through the results of `$('.HS_MerchantId')` and get the values of each result.

Comment: thank you so much dear....can u please edit above code as you are saying??

Comment: no, that is for you to do, Stackoverflow is not meant to develop your code, next to that, I haven't the foggiest what the rest of the system looks like